# Create a fetch query in a file and show it in another file

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I  have a question with OOP on PHP and MySQL.

I'm working with PHP 7 using OOP, I want make a class Connection. In these class
I have a method that generates a query to the database and store it in an array. I want the result of that array to be opened in another class of another file.
If I use an if statement, a single value is sent, if I use a while loop, nothing is shown when I request the vector in the other file.
I want to create this method to avoid having to rewrite the calls to the connection with the database.

This is the code that will inherit the class that shows the data.

```
public function open_connection()
{ 
    $this->connect = new mysqli( self::$SERVER, self::$USER, self::$PASS, $this->DB ) or die ( "Error" ); 
} 

public function close_connection()
{ 
    mysqli_close( $this->connect ); 
}

protected function execute_a_fetch_query( )
{
    $this->open_connection();
    $orderA = $this->connect->query( $this->query );
    $orderB = $this->connect->query( $this->query );
    if ( $this->rows = mysqli_fetch_array( $orderA ) ) { //this sentence avoid a duplicate result from the query
        if ( $this->rows = mysqli_fetch_array( $orderB ) );
    }
    $this->close_connection();
}
```

And here the another method in the Show class

```
public function data( $attributes = array() )
{
    $this->query = 'select * from Supplier';
    $this->execute_a_fetch_query();

    echo '<tr>';

    for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $this->_attributes ); $i++ ) {
        echo 
            '<td>'. $this->rows[ $attributes[ $i ] ]. '</td>'; 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In OOP you have a constructor that can help you out by establishing that connection when you instantiate that object so you wont have to use `$this->open_connection();` in every query.

Instead of creating an `open_connection()` function use

```
function __ construct(){
  $this->connect = new mysqli( self::$SERVER, self::$USER, self::$PASS, $this->DB ) or 
    die ( "Error" );
 }
```

so `$obj = new BaseClass();` will open up a connection.

you can also have a private variable in the same class

`private $dataObject` which can be set in your query `$this->$dataObject = $result;`

and a public function which can be called to return the variable.

```
public function getData()
{
  return $this->$dataObject;
}
```